# How to create this type of dialog in android studio with java?

Tags: java, xml, android-recyclerview, android-popupwindow

I want to show this popup dialog when user select any image from recyclerview and this popup dialog this image by down arrow as showing in image.

[image: popup-image-example]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library called "[Balloon](https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon)" and consider the examples that come. Or you can choose to make your own using "[PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow)".